# Collation conflict using except SQL Server

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, t-sql, plsql, collation

I am trying to execute the following query on two different databases with difent collations

```
select * from sourcedb.DBO.PKtable 
except 
select * from destinationdb.DBO.PKtable
```

It is clear that both the tables have the same columns and the primary key

But when executing, encountered the following exception

> Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 17
>   Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CS_AS" in the EXCEPT operation.

I cannot use `COLLATE` keyword because.. I will be using the above query at runtime and the table name and columns vary, hence cannot predict the columns of the table.

I have tried to change the collation of the destination database to same as the source database using the following command

```
ALTER DATABASE destinationDB SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE 
ALTER DATABASE destinationDB COLLATE <<sourceCollation>>;
ALTER DATABASE destinationDB SET MULTI_USER
```

The collation is set to the database and I can see it from the `sys` tables.

Even then when I execute the query mentioned above, getting the same error

EDIT1: Basically I'm trying to get the records which have the same primary key but difference in the row.

Comment: No, I cannot Use COLLATE until i mention a Column on which im trying to COLLATE.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible workaround (apart from dynamic sql) might be to use a temporary table. (This may suit if this is a one off type of operation).

```
-- create empty #PKTable with required columns and collation. 
select * INTO #PKTable from sourcedb.DBO.PKtable where 1=0

-- fill table with data
insert #PKTable select * from destinationdb.DBO.PKtable

-- compare
select * from sourcedb.DBO.PKtable 
except 
select * from  #PKTable 

-- remove temp table
drop table #PKTable
```

Comment: Thanks, but does that going to impact the performance if the table has huge amount of the data?

Comment: yes, possibly, as a copy of the table is being made. There will also be no primary key on the temporary table, which may also make the comparison slower.